# Creating table or multi-dimensional grid using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, datagrid, html-table

I'm trying to create a word search puzzle and am beginning by generating a table of random letters. I want to have a table of any number by number, so 10X10 for example, but so far I'm only able to generate a column and can't figure out how to create more columns or the entire grid.

```
var firstCol = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ';
    var random = parseInt(Math.random()*characters.length);
    var letter = characters.charAt(random); //returning random letter
    var innerArrays = ['<td>' + letter + '</td>'];
    firstCol.push(innerArrays);
};


for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    document.getElementById('wsBox').innerHTML += 
    '<tr>'+ firstCol[i] + '</tr>';
};
```

and this is my HTML...

```
<table>
    <tbody id="wsBox">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @PauAI: Could had written it as answer instead of comment.

Comment: @noob Rewritten it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic code.

```
var cols = 10; 
var rows = 10; 
var html = ""; 

for(var i =0; i <= rows; i++) { 
    html += '<tr>'; 
    for(var h=0; h<= cols; h++) { 
       var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'; 
       var random = parseInt(Math.random()*characters.length);
       var letter = characters.charAt(random); //returning random letter
       html += '<td>' + letter + '</td>'; 
    } 
    html += '</tr>'; 
}

document.getElementById('wsBox').innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: +1 for answering first. According to me this algorithm should have more entropy. In some cases characters are repeated consecutively.

Comment: There's no need to redefine `characters` with each loop iteration.

Comment: We don't know what's source of rows for the word puzzles, so it's probably in the correct place as it would have different data in each iteration.

Comment: @PaulAl Wow...my code was so mixed up. Your code is simple and sensible. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Here's working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/42dj7jy8/3/

Script

```
var rows = [];
var colStr = null;
for(var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    colStr = "";
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ';
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
      var random = parseInt(Math.random()*characters.length);
      var letter = characters.charAt(random); //returning random letter
      var cell = '<td>' + letter + '</td>';
      colStr += cell;
  };
  rows.push('<tr>' + colStr + '</tr>');
}


document.getElementById('wsBox').innerHTML += rows.join("");
```

Some CSS to wash it down with

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Here's output

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to be able to vary the dimensions of the grid. Your code doesn't account for that.

Comment: Her question says she doesn't code much, I just put her code with changes there to avoid her confusion.

Comment: Her question doesn't say that she doesn't code much.

Answer (score -2):

This uses arrays to build the cells and rows of the grid which are joined together with the `join` method. Simply pass the dimensions of the grid into the function. One loop only.

```
function createGrid(x, y) {
  var rows = [], cells = [];
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ';

  // a complete grid is x * y dimensions
  for (var i = 0, l = x * y; i < l; i++) {
    letter = characters.charAt(Math.random() * characters.length);
    cells.push('<td>' + letter + '</td>');

    // when we reach the last column of the row
    // push the cells into the row array and reset
    // the cells array
    if (i !== 0 && (i + 1) % x === 0) {
      rows.push('<tr>' + cells.join('') + '</tr>');
      cells = [];
    }
  }
  return rows.join('');
}
```

Grab the element and use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add the compiled grid HTML.

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('wsBox');
tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createGrid(10, 10));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/rzrgL3yo/3/) - 10 x 10 grid

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/rzrgL3yo/6/) - 3 x 4 grid

Comment: Give the reason for the downvote, please, because this code works and is exactly to spec.

Comment: If you're aiming for efficiency using x*y look at the @PauAl's answer, that's the most efficient and understandable one.

Comment: How is using 2 loops more efficient than using 1? If you don't understand my code, that's fine, but don't downvote a perfectly useful and accurate answer for that reason.

Comment: Are seriously counting loops for asymptotic algorithmic complexity ? your code has same time complexity as his, I meant in terms of size of code and ease of understanding.

Comment: My code has the same number of lines as Paul's code, and I've added comments to explain what's going on. I'm sorry you don't understand it.

Comment: You're using 2 arrays when there's need of none.

Comment: Then you should probably remove the array from your code, shouldn't you.

Comment: Already said, I was aiming for least changes required, I achieved my goal.